# How to unnest a JSON-type field into a bunch of new fields?

Tags: python, pandas

So I've got a dataframe where one of the columns is of type JSON:

```
In [34]: df.iloc[0]
Out[34]:
user_id                                         lashdgfalsjdhgflajs
json_col               {'foo': True, 'bar': 666, 'baz': 'luhrmann'}
created                                  2019-01-16 07:02:30.137709
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Every record in `json_col` has the same schema — what's the best way to transform this into looking more like, unnesting the JSON in every record along the way?

```
user_id                                         lashdgfalsjdhgflajs
foo                                                            True
bar                                                             666
baz                                                      'luhrmann'
created                                  2019-01-16 07:02:30.137709
```

Obviously I could do stuff with `.apply()` but I'm wondering if there's anything more panda-esque I could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
jscol=pd.DataFrame(df['json_col'].tolist(),index=df.index)    
yourdf=pd.concat([df.drop('json_col',1),jscol],axis=1)
```